# Filtering arrays based on a property value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filtering

There are two classes called `Event` and `Agenda`.

```
class Event {
    let id: Int
    var title: String
    var allDay: Int = 0
    let location: String
    var description: String?
    var startDate: NSDate!
    var endDate: NSDate!
}

class Agenda {
    var date: NSDate!
    var events = [Event]()
}
```

And I have an array of these `Event` objects.

I need to filter this events array out based on it's `startDate` property.

For example say there are 11 events. (I'm only showing the startDates here)

```
2015-07-20
2015-07-21
2015-07-21
2015-07-22
2015-07-22
2015-07-22
2015-07-23
2015-07-23
2015-07-24
2015-07-24
2015-07-24
```

I need to filter this array and create an array of `Agenda` objects. Like this.

```
+------------+----------------+
|    date    | events (count) |
+------------+----------------+
| 2015-07-20 |              1 |
| 2015-07-21 |              2 |
| 2015-07-22 |              3 |
| 2015-07-23 |              2 |
| 2015-07-24 |              3 |
+------------+----------------+
```

I tried iterating through the events array and do it like below.

```
public func filterByDate(events: [Event]) {
    var agendas = [Agenda]()
    for event in events {
        if agendas.isEmpty {
            var agenda = Agenda()
            agenda.date = event.startDate!
            agenda.events.append(event)

            agendas.append(agenda)
        } else {
            let lastAgenda = agendas.last!
            let lastEventOfLastAgenda = lastAgenda.events.last!

            if isSameDate(date1: event.startDate!, date2: lastEventOfLastAgenda.startDate!) {
                lastAgenda.events.append(event)
            } else {
                var agenda = Agenda()
                agenda.date = event.startDate!
                agenda.events.append(event)

                agendas.append(agenda)
            }
        }
    }
}

func isSameDate(#date1: NSDate, date2: NSDate) -> Bool {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components: NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear

    let date1Components = calendar.components(components, fromDate: date1)
    let date2Components = calendar.components(components, fromDate: date2)

    let date1 = calendar.dateFromComponents(date1Components)!
    let date2 = calendar.dateFromComponents(date2Components)!
    let result = date1.compare(date2)
    if result == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

But the result I get is incorrect. I get 6 objects in the `agendas` array. When I just iterate through it, I get the following output.

```
2015-07-20  -   1
2015-07-21  -   1
2015-07-21  -   2
2015-07-22  -   4
2015-07-24  -   1
2015-07-24  -   2
```

I can't figure out where it's going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

By the way even if I get this method to work it's still very messy and not very *Swift-like*. Is there a more elegant way to do this in Swift?

Comment: This only works if your original array is sorted by date. Also, is it not possible that your dates have also hours:minutes:seconds, and not all are at midnight on that specific day? Therefore the date comparison would return false and you would end up creating a new agenda.

Comment: A better question would be, is the array of events sorted by the start date?

Comment: @Yarneo Yes, the events array is sorted by the `startDate`. That date list of 11 events is the output of that.

Comment: @Levi I specifically check only the date component. I updated my question with the function that does the date comparison. Please see above.

Comment: If this is always the output, you can go to the 3rd iteration with the debugger, and see what is wrong there (for the date 2015-07-21)

Comment: @Levi It seems there is something fishy going on with the date comparison. For example when I pass this dates pair into the method it looks like this `current: 2015-07-21 01:30:00 +0000 - last: 2015-07-20 03:30:00 +0000` but after it breaks those down and rebuild the dates from components, it looks like this `current: 2015-07-20 07:00:00 +0000 - last: 2015-07-19 07:00:00 +0000`. The date values have changed.

Comment: @Levi Setting the timezone of the calendar to GMT like this `calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")!` actually solved the entire issue! But I'm not too sure about hardcoding something like the timezone is the best way to go about this.

Comment: Using GMT doesn't really sound like hardcoding to me, since it is the base timezone, so I think you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try a more elegant way:

```
var events: [Event] = Your Event Array Here ...

var groupedDates: [NSDate: Int] = [:] 

for event in events {
    if let number = groupedDates[event.startDate] {
        groupedDates[event.startDate] = number + 1
    }else{
        groupedDates[event.startDate] = 1
    }
}

println(groupedDates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I have further simplified this by adding an `itit()` to the `Agenda` class. I believe that this concisely does what you have asked (this is Swift 2 in Xcode 7 beta 4). It creates an array of `Agenda` objects `[Agenda]` called `agendaArray`.

Assuming we have an array of `Event` objects called `eventArray` where `Event` is declared as in your question.

Here is my solution:

```
var agendaArray = [Agenda]()
for date in Set(eventArray.filter{$0.startDate != nil}.map{$0.startDate}) {
    agendaArray.append(Agenda(date: date, events: eventArray.filter({$0.startDate == date})))
} // populates [Agenda] for each unique date
```

Here is the modified `Agenda` class:

```
class Agenda {
// ...
init(date: NSDate!, events: [Event]){
    self.date = date
    self.events = events
}
```

Quickly test it (first have to sort by date since resulting array has no fixed order):

```
// quickly test it
agendaArray = agendaArray.sort({ $0.date.compare($1.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }) // sort it by date
for eachAgenda in agendaArray {
    print("\(eachAgenda.date)")
    print("count = \(eachAgenda.events.count)")
}
```

Comment: @Isuru - I have further simplified this answer to make it even more concise. Still wondering if it is possible to completely eliminate the `for` loop.